# html css Яндекс изменение размеров окна рушит верстку

Tags: html, css

у меня есть сайт, body которого задан `height: 100%;` Всё отлично отображается, но когда я в Яндексе отпускаю панель, размер доступной области меняется, и вёрстка едет, я решал это двумя способами, задавал `position: relative; overflow: auto-y;` Это помогает, недопускать отпускание панели, но оставляет прокрутку и в целом не решение, также я с помощью `jquery resize` задавал `height: 100hv;` Но это тоже рушит вёрстку пожалуйста подскажите что не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `min-height: 100%;`.

Comment: К сожалению нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось, на второй день. Для начала я всё же задал `min-height: 100%;`
Затем html `positon: absolute;` И в js:

```js
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('html').height(window.innerHeight);
    });
```